# Including authentication with Rails 3.2.8 and Mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

I’m using Rails 3.2.8 with Mongomapper driver to connect to Mongodb 2.0.7. Everything works great and now I would like to include authentication procedure to my Rails application. I looked in to using Devise but most documentation are supporting Mongoid. Please do you know of any solution similar to devise that is suitable for Mongomapper, I really don’t want to revise to Mongoid at this 
point if it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: how about this fork of railsApps https://github.com/ashrocket/rails3-mongomapper-devise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has_secure_password works pretty well with MongoMapper.

Ryan Bates has a Railscast on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

Comment: that was a great starting point, has_secure_password makes the implementation much easier. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much build your own auth mechanism with this Gist: https://gist.github.com/147427